# Sed a plist file gives a iilegal byte sequence

Tags: sed, osx

With a Unix Mac 10.9.5, French CA version
I've read a lot of tips but if the error is gone, the plist is corrupted.

the locale command gives:

```
LANG="fr_CA"
LC_COLLATE="fr_CA"
LC_CTYPE="fr_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_CA"
LC_MONETARY="fr_CA"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_CA"
LC_TIME="fr_CA"
LC_ALL=
```

The file is a plist, called test.mac.plist and looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>bookmarklist.expansionStates</key>
    <dict>
        <key>GENEREAL</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>

</dict>
</plist>
```

the scripted or lined command is sed -i '.bak' « s/xxxxx/test/g » test.mac.plist

1. I've got an illegal byte swquence error
2. if I do as recommanded with chaninge LC_TYPE to LC_TYPE=C
   the file becomes

bplist00ﬂ

```
            ¬ !"+ -./ 2 34' 89: _ >
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Please post the output of `od -An -t x1 <test.mac.plist`. That will let us see if there's anything weird in that file such as a non-printable character. Also, copy-paste the full error message from running `LC_MESSAGES=C sed -i '.bak' « s/xxxxx/test/g » test.mac.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

Your plist file has been converted to a binary plist file. Best practice would be to use either defaults or PlistBuddy to perform changes on the plist file. Either will write to XML or binary plist files. I'm guessing that you wish to change the key GENERAL to false in your example. With PlistBuddy you must first delete the whole entry then add the entry back in to the file.
Delete the whole entry:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :bookmarklist.expansionStates" /path/to/file
```

Then add the entry back in with the new boolean:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :bookmarklist.expansionStates:GENERAL bool false" /path/to/file
```

Using defaults requires that the plist file resides in a proper domain and is less flexable then using PlistBuddy. You may need to prefix these commands with LC_TYPE=C or LC_ALL=C.